# Python: Correcting the local time in a timestamp

Tags: python, time, sublimetext

Using https://gist.github.com/jordan-brough/4007432 I got a timestamp to work in sublime but the time is off by 7 hours. How can I fix this? Do I need to set the timezone?

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
from datetime import datetime

class TimestampCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
 def run(self, edit):
   stamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M %p - ")
   for r in self.view.sel():
    if r.empty():
      self.view.insert (edit, r.a, stamp)
    else:
      self.view.replace(edit, r,   stamp)
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what you get instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `datetime.utcnow()` with `datetime.now()`

UTC = Coordinated Universal Time which has 0 time offset