# Changelog / Header / TimeStamp Plugin for Sublime Text?

Tags: plugins, timestamp, sublimetext2, changelog

I am looking for a simple **Sublime Text 2** plugin that will allow me to:

- Insert (hopefully automatically, but not necessary) a short template with

`% Created: TIMESTAMP`

`% Modified: TIMESTAMP`

and then will replace the first `TIMESTAMP` once and the second every time the file is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FileHeader](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileHeader) plugin for ST provides this functionality and much more.

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin will get you a timestamp (modified from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17650129/1426065)):

```py
import sublime_plugin
from datetime import datetime

class TimeStampCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):
        # formatting options at http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior
        stamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC")  # 2013-07-18 14:54:23 UTC
        # to get the local time, change utcnow() to now()
        for r in self.view.sel():
            if r.empty():
                self.view.insert(edit, r.a, stamp)
            else:
                self.view.replace(edit, r, stamp)
```

Save it as `Packages/User/time_stamp.py` and bind it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> by adding

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"], "command": "time_stamp" }
```

to your keymap (`Preferences->Key Bindings - User`).

Making a plugin to *automatically* update the timestamp is slightly more complex, involving calling an event listener. I'm still debugging it, so check back for more...

Comment: Thanks, MattDMo. There are some plugings like the one you outline (it works great, by the way). But the automatic replacement is really the killer feature I'm looking for. 

In my Vim days, this is what I used for this:

http://is.gd/dwikEx

Comment: A automated plugin would be nice. Use a placeholder like this for it.

Also a current time would be nice, for me its UTC+2).

Thanks

Comment: @user759235 to get the local time, change the `utcnow()` function to `now()` and you should be all set. An tab-triggered snippet shouldn't be too hard to come up with, I'll let you know when I have one.

Comment: any progress on the plugin?

Comment: @AhmadAzwarAnas it works fine for me using both ST2 and ST3 on Win8. Are you sure you set the key binding correctly?

Comment: of course. I set it up correctly. And I already use basic notepad plugin for those, It works on linux properly. Thanks.